# With which I can change the method load() if it is deprecated?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

```
public function getShipAddress($customerId){
    $customer = $this->_customerFactory->create()->load($customerId);    //insert customer id

    //shipping
    $shippingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultShipping();
    $shippingAddress = $this->_addressFactory->create()->load($shippingAddressId);

    return $shippingAddress;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `RepositoryInterface` to load instead of model `load()` function

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
    ...
) {
    $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
}

public function getShipCustomer($customerId)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer */
    $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);

    $shippingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultShipping();
    /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $shippingAddress */
    $shippingAddress = $this->addressRepository->getById($shippingAddressId);

    return $shippingAddress;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- `Models` are Data Interface are used to only hold the data in objects, i.e to `set` and  `get` data for a row.
- `ResourceModels` are a mechanism which is responsible for the persistence of such data, i.e execute the SQL query to actually `save` or `load` data into the `Model` object.

The correct way to `load` and `save` should be by creating a **repository** or **loading from a resource** as follows:

```
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Model;

class QueueRepository
{

    /** @var \MyVendor\MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\Queue  */
    public $resource;

    /** @var \MyVendor\MyModule\Model\QueueFactory  */
    public $modelFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \MyVendor\MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\Queue $resource,
        \MyVendor\MyModule\Model\QueueFactory $modelFactory
    ) {
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->modelFactory = $modelFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Save
     * @param \MyVendor\MyModule\Api\Data\QueueInterface $queue
     * @return $queue
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function save(\MyVendor\Integrator\Api\Data\QueueInterface $queue)
    {
        $this->resource->save($queue);
        return $queue;
    }

    /**
     * Save
     * @param \MyVendor\MyModule\Api\Data\QueueInterface $queue
     * @param int $id
     * @return $queue
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function load(\MyVendor\MyModule\Api\Data\QueueInterface $queue, $id)
    {
        $this->resource->load($queue, $id);
        return $queue;
    }

    public function getById($id)
    {
        $queue = $this->modelFactory->create();
        $this->resource->load($queue, $id);
        return $queue;
    }
}
```

Here, `\MyVendor\MyModule\Api\Data\QueueInterface` is implimented by `Queue` Model.

So, behind the scenes, we are actually creating an `Model` object then `loading` it by the `ResourceModel` object.
This is the correct way to load or save.

```
        $queue = $this->modelFactory->create();
        $this->resource->load($queue, $id);
        return $queue;
```